# Java application stops without any error message or exception

Tags: java, debugging

I am developing a Java application that runs fine on several hundred machines, both Windows and Linux (using latest Oracle JRE). However, on one Windows 7 64-bit machine the application won't run.

Interesting fact: If started from command line via `java -jar MyApp.jar` then the application "just fails" and returns to the shell, without **any** message at all.

In order to find the problem I wrapped the whole content within `main()` like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    try
    {
        // Init. Swing GUI, run application ...
    }
    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, even with this `try-catch`block I still don't get any message on command line.

Can you recommend any other ways for me to find out where the problem could be?

Comment: May the JVM on that Windows machine in screwed up. Download another one, maybe even 32bit and see what happens.

Comment: Can you run other Java applications on that machine? Other Swing applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the records: we needed to install the 64bit version of the JRE, now the application is working like a charm again :)

Answer (score 0):

if possible enable debug method on that machine. otherwise. you may write some debug lines to a log file external to the jar. so that, you will know whether JVM calls the the main method or not.
also try to check java version on that machine if your jar is depending on the specific jre on the windows 7 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your application is running without an exception. However, it's simply not rendering as expected.

One simple diagnostic should provide some more info. Add a "-verbose" switch to your command line. That will print all the classes loaded during your application invocation.

```
$> java -verbose -jar MyApp.jar
```

Should show some additional info. Note! make sure you add -verbose as the first argument like I demoed above.

Hopefully that get's you started.

Also, you can add a System.out.println("SOME MESSAGE") as the first line in your try block. That might help also.

Comment: I tried it with the -verbose flag already. But that has not helped, it only showed me what resources have been loaded, but no indication of an error at all.

Comment: No problem. That was my point, it's running (no error), it's just not appearing on the screen where you expect it. Have you checked to see if there is a "process" running with your app. Make sure you are centering the main frame of you app. Good luck :)

Comment: Typo in my comment:( Should read "see if there is a process running associated with your app". In addition, try substituting a simple fram e the forces focus like:  JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("main");
            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame,  "A simple test.");
            
            mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);